# How to config Windows Server 2008 for accessing through it to the Internet?

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-connection, netlimiter

In our Company we have almost 21 PCs and Laptops. one of them is Server with Windows Server 2008.All of these Computers connected to the Internet through a `ASUS DSL-N10 Wireless ADSL Modem Router`.

We wanna manage clients Internet Bandwidth (For limiting their bandwidth), so we install `NetLimiter 3` on the server.

Now we should config server for connecting clients to it for accessing to the Internet, and after that NetLimiter collect their bandwidth information and we can limit clients with NetLimiter.

How can we config `Windows Server 2008` for connecting and accessing clients to the Internet through it?

Comment: Are you wanting to route traffic via the server? I assume this sever is in their office and provides their DNS etc?

Comment: This server is in our office, this server isn't DNS. Actually we wanna route web traffic via the server

Comment: Well, `ASUS DSL-N10 Wireless ADSL Modem Router` has DHCP Server. Should we have DNS server?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have miss-understood. Are you saying you want your client to use their connection to connect to your server so they can become limited?

Comment: OK, let me describe a little bit more. We have a LAN, All PCs can access to the Internet via `ADSL Modem`. We don't like it, because we can't manage their Internet bandwidth. We installed Windows Server 2008 on a PC within LAN. Now we wanna config Windows Server 2008 such that other PCs can connect to this Windows server and after connecting they will have the Internet. Is it clear?

Comment: Ok, are they on a domain then via the W2k8 machine? Either way, you just need to disable DHCP on the router, enable it on the server (where you can configure default gateway etc)...

Comment: Thanks, but please post it as an Answer and please describe how we can enable DHCP on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: @DaveRook: Our LAN is WorkGroup base, not a domain. Do we have a Domain for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've only done this when they are on a domain but you need to disable DHCP on the router, enable it on the server (where you can configure default gateway etc)...

On the router, there should be a check box to disable the DHCP

> Installing Windows Server 2008 DHCP Server
>
> Installing Windows Server 2008 DCHP Server is easy. DHCP Server is now
>   a “role” of Windows Server 2008 – not a windows component as it was in
>   the past.
>
> To do this, you will need a Windows Server 2008 system already
>   installed and configured with a static IP address. You will need to
>   know your network’s IP address range, the range of IP addresses you
>   will want to hand out to your PC clients, your DNS server IP
>   addresses, and your default gateway. Additionally, you will want to
>   have a plan for all subnets involved, what scopes you will want to
>   define, and what exclusions you will want to create.
>
> To start the DHCP installation process, you can click Add Roles from
>   the Initial Configuration Tasks window or from Server Manager à Roles
>   à Add Roles.
>
> Adding a new Role in Windows Server 2008
>
> When the Add Roles Wizard comes up, you can click Next on that screen.
>
> Next, select that you want to add the DHCP Server Role, and click
>   Next.
>
> Selecting the DHCP Server Role
>
> If you do not have a static IP address assigned on your server, you
>   will get a warning that you should not install DHCP with a dynamic IP
>   address.
>
> At this point, you will begin being prompted for IP network
>   information, scope information, and DNS information. If you only want
>   to install DHCP server with no configured scopes or settings, you can
>   just click Next through these questions and proceed with the
>   installation.
>
> On the other hand, you can optionally configure your DHCP Server
>   during this part of the installation.
>
> In my case, I chose to take this opportunity to configure some basic
>   IP settings and configure my first DHCP Scope.
>
> I was shown my network connection binding and asked to verify it, like
>   this:
>
> Network connection binding
>
> What the wizard is asking is, “what interface do you want to provide
>   DHCP services on?” I took the default and clicked Next.
>
> Next, I entered my Parent Domain, Primary DNS Server, and Alternate
>   DNS Server (as you see below) and clicked Next.
>
> Entering domain and DNS information
>
> I opted NOT to use WINS on my network and I clicked Next.
>
> Then, I was promoted to configure a DHCP scope for the new DHCP
>   Server. I have opted to configure an IP address range of
>   192.168.1.50-100 to cover the 25+ PC Clients on my local network. To do this, I clicked Add to add a new scope. As you see below, I named
>   the Scope WBC-Local, configured the starting and ending IP addresses
>   of 192.168.1.50-192.168.1.100, subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, default
>   gateway of 192.168.1.1, type of subnet (wired), and activated the
>   scope.
>
> Adding a new DHCP Scope
>
> Back in the Add Scope screen, I clicked Next to add the new scope
>   (once the DHCP Server is installed).
>
> I chose to Disable DHCPv6 stateless mode for this server and clicked
>   Next.
>
> Then, I confirmed my DHCP Installation Selections (on the screen
>   below) and clicked Install.
>
> Confirm Installation Selections
>
> After only a few seconds, the DHCP Server was installed and I saw the
>   window, below:
>
> Windows Server 2008 DHCP Server Installation succeeded
>
> I clicked Close to close the installer window, then moved on to how to
>   manage my new DHCP Server.

[Source](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/How-to-Install-Configure-Windows-Server-2008-DHCP-Server.html)